# Pattern matching in rails ( "where column LIKE '%foo%") with Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Person model that includes names, and I want to search these as simply as possible.

Is there a rails/ActiveRecord method along the lines of `People.like(:name => "%#{query}%")`, like what DataMapper has? I couldn't find anything like this in the ActiveRecord docs but I'm shocked if it's simply not possible.

Currently I have it doing `Person.where "name LIKE '%#{query}%'"`, which works great but is an obvious SQL-injection vulnerability.

Rails 3.2

Comment: Isnt postgres use ILIKE instead of LIKE ?

Comment: "The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension."

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use a parameterized query instead to avoid SQL-injections, like so:

```
Person.where('name LIKE ?', '%' + query + '%')
```

Note that the percent signs **must** be part of the parameter, not the `where` clause or Rails will escape it and you'll get a syntax error. (At least on postgres.)

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: ...name LIKE %'John...
                     ^
```